# node-sass@4.5.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I am trying to build angular-cli on jenkins and getting below error. I am using node (v6.10.0) and npm( v3.10.10). I don't have any direct dependency for node-sass in my package.json so it looks like a peer dependency. I have google this error and it looks like there is some issue with node/npm version. I am using latest version of node so really not sure what's the issue here.

node-sass@4.5.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`

> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>     npm ERR!
>     npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.1 postinstall script 'node
>     scripts/build.js'.
>     npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
>     installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,npm ERR! not with npm itself.

Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js

Comment: What version of node are you using for this build.

Comment: just to update. I was able to bypass this error after angular-cli made node-sass as an optional dependency.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this "npm install node-sass@2"

Comment: Provide some more details, please

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Answer (score 1):

by force installing node-sass locally: `npm install -f node-sass`

I was pretty sure I knew what I was doing... [this](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1980)